# Create AccessRules in modules Yii Framework

Tags: yii

in modules\administrator\components\AdminController:

```
class AdminController extends CController
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return array('accessControl');
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('deny', 'users' => array('*')),
        );
    }
}
```

in modules\administrator\controllers\Sitecontroller:

```
class SiteController extends AdminController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }

        public function actionLogin()
        {
                $this->render('login');
        }
}
```

but when visit mydomain.site/administrator/site/index, it does not redirect to mydomain.site/administrator/site/login which redirects to mydomain.site/site/login (default login), I want it redirects to mydomain.site/administrator/site/login

can someone help me?

Comment: Please check the below answer. The redirection to `login` will only happen if it is mentioned that the `action` is to be allowed for authenticated users only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform below actions
      'actions'=>array('index'),
      'users'=>array('@'),
), 
array('deny',  // deny all users
      'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

This way, when the url is requested for `site/index` and as we have set `index` to be allowed only for authenticated users, the request will be redirected to `site/login` (or default login).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set [CWebUser::$loginUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginUrl-detail) before filters are invoked:

```
class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{
 public function init()
  {
   $this->setImport(array(
    'admin.models.*',
   //'application.models.*',
    'admin.components.*',
  ));
 }

 public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
 {
  if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
 {
  // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
   // you may place customized code here
 if ( !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin') ) {
 if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
  $url = Yii::app()->createUrl(Yii::app()->user->loginUrl);
 Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->createUrl('/admin/');
 Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
}
 else {
  throw new CHttpException(403,'Have no permission');
 }
 }
 return true;
 }
 else
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: it working, but when admin login success, it redirect admin homepage and this is error: You are not authorized to perform this action. can u help me?

Comment: check your access rules what is blocking there.

Comment: It should have , `array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform below actions
    'actions'=>array('index'),
    'users'=>array('@'),
),
array('deny',  // deny all users
    'users'=>array('*'),
),`